"Cannot find module '/var/task/lib/commonMiddleware' imported from /var/task/handlers/getAuction.js","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND" - Serverless Node
When I call my endpoint I get the error below:
 Streaming new logs for function: "placeBid"

 INIT_START Runtime - Version: nodejs:20.v42     Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:sa-east-1::runtime:af2737389420ddcdbcdc4db3585842c334ad2482127c15295905f54a62feefc6

 2024-10-20 17:41:33.920 - undefined -

 ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Cannot find module '/var/task/lib/commonMiddleware' imported from /var/task/handlers/getAuction.js","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND","url":"file:///var/task/lib/commonMiddleware","stack":\["Error \[ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND\]: Cannot find module '/var/task/lib/commonMiddleware' imported from /var/task/handlers/getAuction.js","    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:269:11)","    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:937:10)","    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1173:14)","    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1216:79)","    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:540:12)","    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:509:25)","    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:239:38)","    at ModuleWrap.\<anonymous\> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:96:40)","    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:95:36)"\]}

 INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 194.75 ms    Phase: init     Status: error  Error Type: Runtime.Unknown

 2024-10-20 17:41:34.689 - undefined -

 ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Cannot find module '/var/task/lib/commonMiddleware' imported from /var/task/handlers/getAuction.js","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND","url":"file:///var/task/lib/commonMiddleware","stack":\["Error \[ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND\]: Cannot find module '/var/task/lib/commonMiddleware' imported from /var/task/handlers/getAuction.js","    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:269:11)","    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:937:10)","    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1173:14)","    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1216:79)","    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:540:12)","    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:509:25)","    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:239:38)","    at ModuleWrap.\<anonymous\> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:96:40)","    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:95:36)"\]}

 INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 949.46 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error  Error Type: Runtime.Unknown

 START - b268505b-edc7-49c1-a4cb-27cc869d550f - Version: $LATEST

 END - b268505b-edc7-49c1-a4cb-27cc869d550f

 REPORT - b268505b-edc7-49c1-a4cb-27cc869d550f

 Duration: 960.51 ms     Billed Duration: 961 ms Memory Size: 256 MB    Max Memory Used: 73 MB  Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown

This is the funtion my endpoint runs it:
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import createError from 'http-errors';
import middy from '@middy/core';
import httpJsonBodyParser from '@middy/http-json-body-parser';
import httpEventNormalizer from '@middy/http-event-normalizer';
import httpErrorHandler from '@middy/http-error-handler';
import { getAuctionById } from './getAuction';

const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

async function placeBid(event, context) {
  const { id } = event.pathParameters;
  const { amount } = event.body;

  const auction = await getAuctionById(id);

  console.log('AUCTIONS', auction);

  if (amount <= auction.highestBid.amount) {
    throw new createError.Forbidden(
      `Your bid must be higher than ${auction.highestBid.amount}!`,
    );
  }

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME,
    Key: { id },
    UpdateExpression: 'set highestBid.amount = :amount',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':amount': amount,
    },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  };

  let updatedAuction;

  try {
    const result = await dynamoDB.update(params).promise();
    updatedAuction = result.Attributes;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new createError.InternalServerError(error);
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(updatedAuction),
  };
}

export const handler = middy(placeBid)
  .use(httpJsonBodyParser())
  .use(httpEventNormalizer())
  .use(httpErrorHandler());

I tryied to chage the way I import the getAuctionById function and how I export this function, below it's the code where I export this function:
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import createError from 'http-errors';
import commonMiddleware from '../lib/commonMiddleware';

const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const getAuctionById = async id => {
  let auction;

  try {
    const result = await dynamoDB
      .get({
        TableName: process.env.AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME,
        Key: { id },
      })
      .promise();

    auction = result.Item;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new createError.InternalServerError(error);
  }

  return auction;
};

async function getAuction(event, context) {
  const { id } = event.pathParameters;
  const auction = await getAuctionById(id);

  if (!auction) {
    throw new createError.NotFound(`Auction with ID "${id}" not found!`);
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(auction),
  };
}

export const handler = commonMiddleware(getAuction);

export { getAuctionById };

I still tryied do export directly in the function declaration and like below:
module.exports = getAuctionById
But I didn't succeeded!

is /var/task/lib/commonMiddleware supposed to be a file or a folder?

@JaromandaX this is a file, it is a middleware

what if you import commonMiddleware from '../lib/commonMiddleware.js';

The uncaught exception error is caused by an extra set of these '} or {'.
Look for an unnecessary bracket and remove them from your code.
I pointed it out and commented it for you. Within your export code. make sure to check through all the code again, especially around the brackets in your code.
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import createError from 'http-errors';
import commonMiddleware from '../lib/commonMiddleware';

const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const getAuctionById = async id => {
  let auction;
  try {
    const result = await dynamoDB
      .get({
        TableName: process.env.AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME,
        Key: { id },
      })
      .promise();

    auction = result.Item;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new createError.InternalServerError(error);

//}  <--- Remove this here:

  return auction;
};

async function getAuction(event, context) {
  const { id } = event.pathParameters;
  const auction = await getAuctionById(id);

  if (!auction) {
    throw new createError.NotFound(`Auction with ID "${id}" not found!`);
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(auction),
  };
//} <--- Remove this

export const handler = commonMiddleware(getAuction);

export { getAuctionById };


This is a close curly braces of catch, I guess this is not the problem. Do you have any other thing in mind?
